# Difference between Cocoa Touch Framework and Cocoa Touch Static Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, frameworks

What is the difference between Cocoa Touch Framework and Cocoa Touch Static Library? 
In which scenario both can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are different things.  There's a bit of a discussion here: [What are Frameworks?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002303-BBCEIJFI)

In a nutshell, though, a static library is a collection of compiled source files which is then linked directly into an app's binary.  That is, it becomes a part of your app's binary.  A framework is a standalone entity that contains a binary containing compiled code (along with any related resources) that is a standalone unit itself.  The page I linked to includes more details on specific differences.